# Socket IO: Number of users in a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using **Socket.IO** `v.1.3.5` for node.JS...

How can I get the number of real users (**not sessions**) that are connected in a room?

### Number of sessions:

```
 var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId] || {};
 var numSocketsInRoom = Object.keys(room).length;
```

But if the same user is connected in multiple browser tabs, the numSocketInRoom is increased because is the number of sessions, and not the real number of users.

In my case, any socket have the user saved in `socket.userId`, but I don't know how indicate this to get the number of users connected in a room...

*Thank you!*

Comment: Well you do have the object for rooms with `roomID`, for the users you could also use the same approach `var users = {}` and add the ID-s there.

Comment: oh, it's a good idea. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Make sure you also remove the disconnected users also, one improvement to update the users list is to add some heartbeat pinging or time based checks.

Comment: I added a answer with my solution. Is heartbeat pinging or time based checks necessary? I used `socket.on('disconnect',callback)`

Comment: Just for invalidating the data about the users, also to make the solution more persistent you should use Redis, MongoDB, if the application crashes you lose your information. The same rule applies if you want to scale you application to more than one instance.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` as the result of `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId]`. I'm using Socket.IO version how to ssee socket.io verison

Answer (score 0):

My solution finally was this code, this code is executed after **join** (`isConnect = true`) or **leave** (`isConnect = false`) the **room**:

```
//Get the room:
var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId] || {};
//Declaration of number of users variable
var numUsers;

//If there are any user connected in the room, create the object
if(room.user===undefined) 
  room.user = {};

//If you join the room and have another opened session, increase the number of sessions
if(room.user[socket.request.user.id] && isConnect)
   room.user[socket.request.user.id] += 1;

//If you leave the room and have another opened session, decrease the number of sessions
else if(room.user[socket.request.user.id] && !isConnect){
    room.user[socket.request.user.id] -= 1;

    //If the number of sessions is 0, delete the user from the object
    if(room.user[socket.request.user.id]===0)
       delete room.user[socket.request.user.id];
 }
//If the user don't have any session and join the room, put 1 session in the object
else if(isConnect){
  room.user[socket.request.user.id] = 1;
}

//Get the number of users from room.user object
numUsers = Object.keys(room.user).length;
```